# jQuery-steps Formwizard and CakePhp not submitting

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, jquery-steps

I have a webform in my CakePHP application *(2.5.4)*, and I am using the jQuery-steps *(1.1.0)* in conjunction with jQuery Validate plugin *(1.13.1)* to make it a multistep form.

All seems to be going well, but the form is not being submitted. Does anybody have an inkling as to how I would get it to work? As far as I can tell, I end up in the `onFinished` event.

Here is my view file:

```
<div class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-10">

    <!--nocache-->
    <?php if($this->Session->flash()) { echo $this->Session->flash(); } ?>
    <?php if($this->Session->flash('auth')) { echo $this->Session->flash('auth') ;} ?>
    <!--/nocache-->

    <?php
    // output success info
    if(isset($this->params['named']['success']) && $this->params['named']['success']=='1') : ?>       
 // Success message
 <?php endif; ?>
    <h1 class="lead">Request Pricing Information</h1>
    <div class="formWrapper">
        <?php echo $this->Form->create();?>
        <div>
            <h2>Select Date</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('date', array(
                        'type' =>  'text',
                        'placeholder' => 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        'label'=> 'What is the date of your event / project?', 'class' => 'required form-control',
                        'div' => 'form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6'
                    )); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clearMe smallContentSpacer ">&nbsp;</div>
            </fieldset>

            <h2>Type of Photography</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <?php
                $options = array(
                    'Wedding Photography' => 'Wedding / Event Photography',
                    'Portrait Photography' => 'Portrait Photography',
                    'Corporate Photography' => 'Corporate Photography',
                    'Other Photography' => 'Other'
                );
                echo $this->Form->input('type_of_photography', array(
                    'options' => $options,
                    'label' => 'What type of photography are you inquiring about?',
                    'empty' => 'Please select',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6'
                ));
                // display error message
                echo $this->Form->error('Contact.type_of_photography');
                ?>

                <div id="photographyDetailsArea" style="display:none">
                    <?php // Weddings ?>
                    <div class="details_weddings" style="clear: both; display:none">
                        <h4>Wedding Details</h4>
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('wedding_venue', array(
                            'label' => 'Reception Venue:',
                            'type' =>  'text',
                            'placeholder'=> 'Reception Venue',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'div' => 'form-group'
                        ));
                        echo $this->Form->input('wedding_venuecity', array(
                            'label' => 'City:',
                            'type' =>  'text',
                            'placeholder' => 'City',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'div' => 'form-group'
                        ));
                        echo $this->Form->input('wedding_venuestate', array(
                            'label' => 'State / Province:',
                            'type' =>  'text',
                            'placeholder' => 'State / Province',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'div' => 'form-group'
                        ));
                        echo $this->Form->input('wedding_venuecountry', array(
                            'label' => 'Country:',
                            'type' =>  'text',
                            'default' => 'USA',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'div' => 'form-group'
                        ));
                        ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php // Portraits ?>
                    <div class="details_portraits" style="clear: both; display:none">
                        <h4>Portrait Details</h4>
                        <div class="radioWrap">
                            <?php
                            $options = array('Studio' => 'Studio', 'Location' => 'Location', 'Not Sure' => 'Not Sure');

                            echo $this->Form->input('portrait_location', array(
                                'type' => 'radio',
                                'before' => '<div class="radio-inline">',
                                'after' => '</div>',
                                'separator' => '</div><div class="radio-inline">',
                                'options' => $options,
                                'value' => 'Not Sure',
                                'legend' => false,
                                'div' => 'form-group'
                            ));

                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php  // Corporate ?>
                    <div class="details_corporate" style="clear: both; display:none">
                        <h4>Corporate Details</h4>
                        <?php
                        $options = array(
                            'Advertising' => 'Advertising',
                            'Editorial' => 'Editorial',
                            'Fashion Shoot' => 'Fashion Shoot',
                            'Other' => 'Other'
                        );

                        echo $this->Form->input('corporate_details', array(
                            'options' => $options,
                            'label' => 'What kind of Corporate Photography are you looking for?',
                            'empty' => false,
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'div' => 'form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6'
                        ));
                        ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php  // Other ?>
                    <div class="details_other" style="clear: both; display:none">
                        <h4>Details</h4>
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('other_photography_details', array(
                            'label' => 'Project Details',
                            'type' =>  'textarea',
                            'rows' => 4,
                            'cols' => 30,
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'div' => 'form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6'
                        ));
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <input name="data[Pricing][validate_options]" value="" id="ContactValidateOptions" type="hidden" />

                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <h2>Personal Information</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array(
                    'label' => 'First Name:',
                    'type' =>  'text',
                    'placeholder' => 'First Name',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group'
                ));
                echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array(
                    'label' => 'Last Name:',
                    'type' =>  'text',
                    'placeholder' => 'Last Name',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group'
                ));
                echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                    'label' => 'Email:',
                    'type' =>  'text',
                    'placeholder' => 'Email',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group'
                ));
                echo $this->Form->input('city', array(
                    'label'=> 'City:',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'placeholder' => 'City',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group'
                ));
                echo $this->Form->input('state', array(
                    'label' => 'State / Province:',
                    'type' =>  'text',
                    'placeholder' => 'State / Province',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group'
                ));
                echo $this->Form->input('country', array(
                    'label' => 'Country:',
                    'type' =>  'text',
                    'default'=>'USA',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group'
                ));
                echo $this->Form->input('phone', array(
                    'label' => 'Phone:',
                    'type' =>  'text',
                    'placeholder' => 'Phone number',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group'
                ));
                ?>
                <?php
                $options = array(
                    array (
                        'name'=> 'Anytime',
                        'value' => 'Anytime',
                        'selected' => 'selected'
                    ),
                    'Morning' => 'Morning',
                    'Noon' => 'Noon',
                    'Afternoon' => 'Afternoon',
                    'Evening' => 'Evening'
                );
                echo $this->Form->input('contact_time', array(
                    'options' => $options,
                    'label' => 'Preferred Contact Time <i>(your timezone)</i>',
                    'empty'=>false,
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => 'form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6'
                ));
                ?>
            </fieldset>

            <h2>Additional Information</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('additional_information', array(
                    'label' => 'Comments:',
                    'type' =>  'textarea',
                    'rows' => 10,
                    'cols' => 30,
                    'class' => 'form-control ignore',
                    'div' => 'form-group'));
                ?>
                <div class="likeLabel"></div><br />
                <?php
                $options = array(
                    'Past Client' => 'Past Client',
                    'Vendor Recommendation' => 'Vendor Recommendation',
                    'Online Forum' => 'Online Forum',
                    'Magazine Feature' => 'Magazine Feature',
                    'Magazine AD - Listing' => 'Magazine advertising or listing',
                    'Other' => 'Other'
                );
                echo $this->Form->input('howdidyoufindus', array(
                    'options' => $options,
                    'label' => 'How did you find us?',
                    'class' => 'form-control ignore',
                    'div' => 'form-group',
                    'empty'=> 'Please select'
                ));
                ?>

                <label for="findusaddtional" class="additionalInfoLabel"></label>
                <div id="additionalInfoArea" class="input text">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('findusadditional', array(
                        'type' =>  'text',
                        'label' => false,
                        'class' => 'form-control ignore',
                        'div' => 'form-group'
                    ));?>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
        <?php $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearMe smallContentSpacer ">&nbsp;</div>
</div><!--class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-10" -->

<?php
// Render Javascript and required files
$this->Html->script(array('jquery.steps','jquery.validate.min', 'infopacketform'), array('block' => 'scriptBottom'));

echo $this->Html->css('multistepForm');
?>
```

Here is the Javascript file which contains the validation + jquery-step call:

```
$(function() {

var form = $("#PricingIndexForm");

// jQuery Validator - add settings for Bootstrap
$.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid",
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent(".input-group").length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }

});

// jQuery Validator - additional validation format for Date
$.validator.addMethod(
    "dateFormat",
    function(value, element) {
        return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
);


// jQuery Validator - Form Validation
form.validate({
    rules: {
        "data[Pricing][date]": { dateFormat:true },
        "data[Pricing][firstname]" : { required: true, minlength: 2},
        "data[Pricing][lastname]" : { required: true, minlength: 2},
        "data[Pricing][email]" : { email: true},
        "data[Pricing][city]" : { required: true, minlength: 2},
        "data[Pricing][state]" : { required: true, minlength: 2},
        "data[Pricing][country]" : { required: true, minlength: 2},
        "data[Pricing][phone]" : { required: true, minlength: 2},
        "data[Pricing][additional_information]" : { required: false},
        "data[Pricing][findusadditional]" : { required: false}
    },
    ignore: ".ignore"
});

form.children("div").steps({
    headerTag: "h2",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {

        if (currentIndex > newIndex)
        {
            return true;
        } else {

            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        }


    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
       // adjust form height to content
       switch(currentIndex) {
           case 0:
               setFormstepContentHeight(200);
               break;

           case 1:
               var selectedOption = $('#PricingTypeOfPhotography').val();

               if( selectedOption === '' ||
                   selectedOption === 'Portrait\ Photography' ||
                   selectedOption === 'Other\ Photography') {
                   setFormstepContentHeight(200);
               } else if ( selectedOption === 'Corporate\ Photography' ) {
                   setFormstepContentHeight(220);
               } else {
                   setFormstepContentHeight(450);
               }
               break;

           case 2:
               setFormstepContentHeight(600);
               break;

           case 3:
               setFormstepContentHeight(450);
               break;
       }

    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        console.log(form);

        // Submit form input
        form.submit();
    }
});

/**
 * Set the height of the form step based on the content
 * @param height
 */
function setFormstepContentHeight(height) {
    $('.wizard>.content').css('height', height + 'px');
}

});
```

I appreciate any input!

Comment: Might be a silly question, but you realise that `debug: true` prevents the form from submitting?

Comment: @scowler - GENIUS! Not a silly question at all - I did not realize that!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @scowler has so graciously pointed out, the issue was that when `debug: true` is set in the `$.validator.setDefaults({...})` the form does not get submitted.

Once set to `false` the form submission works without flawlessly.